# Donald Knuth and change of variable operation on sum

Tags: summation, change-of-variable

I am reading the very first Donald Knuth book on Algorithms, chapter 1.2.3. "Sum and Products" (p.30).

Donald Knuth introduces operations on sum. But I can't fully understand the 1 example that utilizes two operations:

- *2. change of variable* (particularly confused by)
- *4. manipulating the domain*

An example of *change of variable* that fully understand the explanation:

$$\sum\limits_{R(i)}a_i = \sum\limits_{R(j)}a_j = \sum\limits_{R(p(j))}a_{p(j)}$$

However, I can't understand the very first example given in the book: how did we come up with $$2j$$ and how this stores all the variables by changing the variable?
The steps are as follows:

$$\sum\limits_{0\le j\le n}a_j=\sum\limits_{0\le j\le n\,j\,even}a_j + \sum\limits_{0\le j\le n \,j\,odd}a_j$$ and then $$\sum\limits_{0\le 2j\le n j\,even}a_{2j} + \sum\limits_{0<=2j+1<=n\,j\,odd}a_{2j+1}$$
$$=\sum\limits_{0<=j<=n/2\,j\,even}a_{2j} + \sum\limits_{0<=j<=n/2j+1\,j\,odd}a_{2j+1}$$

Comment: the line after "and then" is wrong, you need to sum over all even numbers, not just summing over $2j$ where $j$ is even; this means you're summing over multiples of 4

Comment: Yes, that's basically my question, however Knuth states that it's valid

Comment: Yes, I agree, but it seems that it misses certain variables. like a_1

Comment: The notation is a bit confusing, and I think there is a misprint/error. I think it is the $2j$ that is meant to be even and the $2j+1$ that is meant to be odd. and the error is in printing $j$ before  $odd$ in the second-last line. If $j$ is an integer then of course $2j$ is automatically even and $2j+1$ is automatically odd.. Using a different letter instead of reusing $j$ with a different meaning would have been clearer, even though $j$ is only a dummy variable.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have an older edition of the book? In the second edition, Example 1 on page 30 reads
$$\begin{align}
\sum_{0 \le j \le n} a_j &= \sum_{\substack{0 \le j \le n \\ j \, \text{even}}} a_j + \sum_{\substack{0 \le j \le n \\ j \, \text{odd}}} a_j \\
&= \sum_{\substack{0 \le 2j \le n \\ 2j \, \text{even}}} a_{2j} + \sum_{\substack{0 \le 2j+1 \le n \\ 2j+1 \, \text{odd}}} a_{2j+1} \\
&= \sum_{0 \le j \le n/2} a_{2j} + \sum_{0 \le j < n/2} a_{2j+1}
\end{align}$$

Comment: I had not realized until just now that the latest edition of *The Art of Computer Programming, Volume 1* is the third, but I have now checked, and the second and third editions agree in this section.